# Is there an add-on for Excel to allow me to sort by an arbitrary column with a SINGLE click?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, sorting, headers

Windows Explorer allows you to sort by an column by clicking on the 'header' of that column so you can see files sorted by size or filename etc.

Excel on the other hand forces you to go through the Sort->Custom Sort window to get the same job done far less efficiently.

Is there a plugin for Excel (I use 2007) to enable an extra row so I can do this with a single click?

Comment: Excel does that by default, man. Click ANYWHERE inside your column, and click the A to Z or Z to A button on the Home tab...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Is there an add-on for Excel to allow me to sort by an arbitrary
>   column with a SINGLE click?**
>
> Excel on the other hand forces you to go through the Sort->Custom Sort
>   window to get the same job done far less efficiently.

Actually, you can natively insert a table like so with your data in Excel 2007. There should be no need for any special add-ons to get this functionality with Excel 2007 (or 2010 for that matter as well).

1. Select all your columns and rows in your Excel worksheet, go to the `Insert` tab, and select the `Table` option.
2. In the `Create Table` dialog window that pops up, select whether or not your data columns have headers or not, and press `OK`.
3. Now your worksheet of data has a selectable filter arrow at the top of each column header to use for sorting each column's value.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**WITHOUT COLUMN HEADERS (still has sort filter single click functionlity per column)**

[image]

Comment: Your solution requires two clicks, but it is quick to accomplish, and the end result allows so much flexibility (such as sorting by colour and filtering) that I decided to tick it!

Answer (score 2):

you can

1. **Put your own buttons** in that extra row. you will have to do that for each column, but the effect is a real single-click. See this Microsoft article on how to do that: https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Add-a-button-and-assign-a-macro-to-it-in-a-worksheet-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283
2. **Use Auto-filters** - they come with 'Sort': Select all your data, the under Data, click Filter. You will get little triangles in the top row over each column, which allow you to sort (and filter) quickly (but with *two* clicks).